# Ports open in router settings, Firewall disabled, no DMZ's, port's still appear as closed, why?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

So I'm currently attempting to host an IIS and opened the nessesary ports, I can connect to it via localhost and on other machines in the network, however when attempting to connect to it over WAN I cannot connect. I've narrowed this down to the fact that port checkers are telling me ALL of my ports of closed. I'm with Bell Alliant (FibreOP) and my router is the Actiontec R1000H, in my router settings, the ports are opened correctly, my firewall is disabled and there are no active DMZ's. Why are my ports still showing up as closed when using port checkers online?

Comment: Technically I would expect DMZ to be enabled, pointed toward the machine, that was hosting the website.  Are you sure the ports are forwarded to the correct machine?

Comment: 100%, double checked this along with some other basic troubleshooting before I made this @Ramhound

Comment: Which port(s) have you tried?  If this is home service from Bell then they may be blocking web server ports/traffic; you should call them and confirm or deny that.

Comment: I need port 80, 1433, 443 and port 35855 opened, I've opened all of them in my router settings, I will contact Bell now.